# .net mvc book for a rails developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I am a rails developer and I am looking for a good .Net MVC book or tutorial. I don't know where to start. Do I have to learn .Net web forms and c# first, or can I go directly through .Net MVC?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to start with Web Form; being a Rails developer, it might even be easier for you to start with ASP.NET MVC. Ultimately, each offers a very different approach to web development and your choice will depend on your specific needs. Many will argue that MVC is the better choice.. realistically, each has its place. Moreover,  keep in mind that not every ASP.NET MVC web application will be built from scratch; several projects will probably end up migrating from classic ASP.NET.

C# is one of many  programming languages available for use in .NET....and although I strongly suggest learning C#, you could -technically speaking- use an implementation of Ruby called 'IronRuby' to get started. Should you first learn C#? Again, it's up to you... though just as it is helpful for a Rails developer to be proficient in Ruby, being comfortable with whichever  language language you choose will prove helpful in learning a new framework. More importantly, the learning curve will seem much steeper if yo try to tackle both at the same time.. C#, can certainly differ from Ruby.

Anyhow, I highly recommend [PluralSight](http://www.PluralSight.com) & [Microsoft's Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

As user3435091 says, you don't need to learn WebForms, that is the old school way to do web applications in ASP.NET (the book detailed below explains why, but basically it has to be with actually web apps tend to be stateless and webforms goes to the opposite direction). With ASP.NET MVC, you will find a fundamental similarity to rails, you have Models, Views and Controllers as you would expect (they both follows MVC which is an architecture), so you don't have to change the way you think today about building a web applications. The template engine MVC uses is Razor which also uses the concepts of views, partial views, layouts, helpers, helpers for ajax, etc (it uses jQuery by default too).
The hardest part to learn I think would be with ORM (you have EntityFramework and NHibernate, the .NET implementation of Java Hibernate :s ) and that C# uses attributes (similar to java annotations). Also, you are not provided with the nice rails console out of the box in .NET.

The book I used to learn ASP.NET MVC 3 (and which I can recommend) is [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3](https://www.apress.com/9781430234043) by Adam Freeman and Steven Sanderson.

Hope that helps.